# How can I redefine a parameter passed to a script?

Tags: powershell

I'm calling a script like this;

```
./pub.ps1 -b ab
```

and in pub I have:

```
param(
   [string]$b
)
```

What I would like is to have some kind of case or switch that redefines the param.

So that entering in:

```
 -b abc as a parameter could be converted to: $bucket = "abcd123"
 -b ddd as a parameter could be converted to: $bucket = "sdafasdf"
```

In other words is there some form of case or switch statement I could use?

Comment: maybe validatescript is a fitting solution if i understand your question correctly

Comment: While it's possible to abuse `ValidateScript()` for this it's *not* a fitting solution. At all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but mapping one string to another can be done for instance with a hashtable:

```
$map = @{
  'abc' = 'abcd123'
  'ddd' = 'sdafasdf'
}

$bucket = $map[$b]
```

or with a [`switch`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) statement:

```
$bucket = switch ($b) {
  'abc'   { 'abcd123' }
  'ddd'   { 'sdafasdf' }
  default { 'something else' }
}
```

The `switch` approach is more versatile, because not only can you have a default value, but you can also do wildcard or regular expression matches instead of plain string matches.